# How to use 'variables of variables' for uploaded files?

Tags: php, file-upload, scope

I'm trying to put uploaded files into cycle to reduce code.

```
<input type="file" name="new1[]" accept="image/*">
<input type="file" name="new2[]" accept="audio/*">
<input type="file" name="new3[]" accept="text/*">
```

And in php there's cycle for these files

```
<?php
 $all=array();
 $all[]=array('new1','Dir_for_1st_type_to_store');
 $all[]=array('new2','Dir for 2nd type');
 $all[]=array('new3','Dir for 3rd type');

 for($i=0;$i<count($all);$i++){
   $newFile=$$all[$i][0]; //that is VAR in VAR trick
   echo $newFile; //that's Ok. Temp files with paths displayed
   echo $newFile_name[$i]; //that's not Ok. No output

 ....................//here is a HUUUUUUGE amount of code, written for 'one file variable'
 }
?>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What kind of sorcery is "**$newFile=$$all[$i][0]; //that is VAR in VAR trick**" do you really think that's a trick??? aw gad

Comment: where does `$newFile_name` come from?

Comment: @Claudio Ludovico Panetta, it's a trick for less code =)

Comment: I dont see how 3 lines of html are reduced by using 10 lines of php?

Comment: @John, it came form '$newFile=$$all[$i][0]', $all[0][0] is 'new1', $all[1][0] is 'new2' atc.

Comment: @EL, yes, but you never actually define `$newFile_name` anywhere, also not using variable variables.

Comment: @John, U say, that the only way is 'if($i==0){$newFile=$new1;} if($i==1){$newFile=$new2;} ' etc?

Comment: No, not at all. Try Kolinks answer!

Comment: @John, I need multiple files for one file's field =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="new1[]" accept="image/*" multiple />
<input type="file" name="new2[]" accept="audio/*" multiple />
<input type="file" name="new3[]" accept="text/*" multiple />
```

PHP:

```
$map = Array(
    "new1"=>"Dir_for_1st_type_to_store",
    "new2"=>"Dir for 2nd type",
    "new3"=>"Dir for 3rd type",
);
foreach($map as $k=>$v) {
    $fileArray = $_FILES[$k];
    $keys = array_keys($fileArray["name"]);
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $newFile = array_map(function($a) use ($key) {return $a[$key];},$fileArray);
        var_dump($newFile); // you should see temp filename and other file info
        var_dump($v); // this should be the target folder
        // do stuff with it
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx, but not working with multiple files.

Comment: Explain furhter what's not working.

Comment: Since you don't actually have the `multiple` attribute anywhere, and you were only ever accessing the 0th index of the resulting array, I assumed that each `input` would receive a single file.

Comment: no, every input has 'multiple' attr. And this is problem, cause " I have a huge amount of php code, written for ONE file var, so I'm trying to put it into a loop without changing".

Comment: Edited answer to support multi-file uploads.

Comment: it seems too complicated for getting var, but thanx.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a silly way** of organizing the `$_FILES` array. This HTML form:

```
<input type="file" name="new1[]" accept="image/*">
<input type="file" name="new1[]" accept="image/*">

<input type="file" name="new2[]" accept="audio/*">
<input type="file" name="new2[]" accept="audio/*">

<input type="file" name="new3[]" accept="text/*">
<input type="file" name="new3[]" accept="text/*">
```

Produces an array similar to:

```
// 1st new1 file
$_FILES["new1"]["name"    ][0]
$_FILES["new1"]["type"    ][0]
$_FILES["new1"]["size"    ][0]
$_FILES["new1"]["tmp_name"][0]
$_FILES["new1"]["error"   ][0]
// 2nd new1 file
$_FILES["new1"]["name"    ][1]
$_FILES["new1"]["type"    ][1]
$_FILES["new1"]["size"    ][1]
$_FILES["new1"]["tmp_name"][1]
$_FILES["new1"]["error"   ][1]
// likewise for 1st new2, 2nd new2, 1st new3, 2nd new3
```

Your code could be written as:

```
$all = array();
$all["new1"] = array("Dir for 1st type");
$all["new2"] = array("Dir for 2nd type");
$all["new3"] = array("Dir for 3rd type");

foreach ($all as $key => $conf) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES[$key]["name"]); $i++) {
        if ($_FILES[$key]["error"][$i] === 0) {
            echo $_FILES[$key]["tmp_name"][$i] . " goes to " . $conf[0] . "\n";
            // HUUUUUUGE amount of code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

** That is just my opinion.

Comment: The problem is that I have a huge amount of php code, written for ONE file var, so I'm trying to put it into a loop without changing.

Comment: I have mentioned where the "HUUUUUUGE amount of code" is supposed to go and an example of how to get a specific property of the uploaded file. Test the script to see if it echoes the correct data for all files. Then inject the huge code.